# Convert variable from datetime.timedelta to numpy.timedelta64

Tags: numpy, timedelta

How to convert a variable from Python's `datetime.timedelta` to `numpy.timedelta64`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
array([datetime.timedelta(1)], dtype="timedelta64[ms]")[0]
```

[This link](https://github.com/plaes/numpy/blob/master/doc/neps/datetime-proposal3.rst) explains many things about `datetime64` and `timedelta64`. 
This is also relevant for converting `datetime.datetime` to `datetime64`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without creating an `np.array` by mapping the fundamental integer representations in `datetime.timedelta` (days, seconds, and microseconds) to corresponding `np.timedelta64` representations, and then summing.

The downside of this approach is that, while you will get the same delta duration, you will not always get the same units. The upside of this approach is that, if you are converting single values rather than large arrays of values, it will generally be faster than creating an array.

You can also just call `np.timedelta64()` with a `datetime.timedelta`, but that approach only returns a `np.timedelta64()` with microsecond units.

```py
from functools import reduce
import operator

TIME_DELTA_ATTR_MAP = (
        ('days', 'D'),
        ('seconds', 's'),
        ('microseconds', 'us')
        )

def to_timedelta64(value: datetime.timedelta) -> np.timedelta64:
    return reduce(operator.add,
        (np.timedelta64(getattr(value, attr), code)
        for attr, code in TIME_DELTA_ATTR_MAP if getattr(value, attr) > 0))
```